# Adobe AIR. Access WebKit low level API and disable Flash and warnings

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm looking for a way to disable Flash Player and security warnings (e.g. ssl warnings) in HTML (or HTMLLoader) component without html modifications, just disable Flash natively.

Maybe WebKit inside Adobe Air has accessible low level API or it is possible to replace WebKit.dll here (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe AIR\Versions\1.0`) with another version without Flash. As I know, Adobe compiles that .dll (Apollo WebKit).

Thanks.

Comment: could you just strip out any HTML that refers to a SWF?

Comment: I'll implement that if nothing else possible. Disable Flash natively would be the best possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

No way to tune webkit inside Adobe Air. Only solution is to preload html, then change like `replace(/<object([^>]+)?>(.*?)<\/object>/gi, '')` and load to htmlloader.